# Is there "a fragment finished attaching" event?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

The only thing I could find that seemed to be relevant was "onAttachFragment". But when I added debug messages, the order was like this.

```
onAttachFragment()
end of activity's onCreate()
beginning of the fragment's onAttach()
```

So, `onAttachFragment` was called before `onAttach`. What if I need to do something in the activity **after** the `onAttach` has been called for the fragment? This is because the fragment's dependency is injected in `onAttach`, and I need to call a method of the fragment in the activity, after the fragment's dependency has been injected.

PS: [The example](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-the-new-dagger-android-module-9eb6075f1a46) I saw was calling `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` in `onAttach()` of a fragment, so I followed it. But, perhaps I could call that in `onCreate()` of the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that with lifecycle methods apart from using `onAttachFragment` (I'd say use `onAttachFragment` but that doesn't work for you) , what you can do is simply devise an interface communication between fragment and activity. Create an interface in your fragment:

```
interface OnFinishAttachCallback{
    void finishedAttached();
}
```

Create a global variable :

```
OnFinishAttachCallback callback;
```

Override (you're already doing this) onAttach:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    callback = (OnFinishAttachCallback) context;
}
```

Make your activity implement the interface and simply call `callback.finishedAttached()` when you want to indicate to your activity that your fragment is ready.